# Is a neural network consisting of a single softmax classification layer only a linear classifier?

Tags: neural-networks, generalized-linear-model, softmax

Since the softmax function is a generalization of the logistic function it is continuous and non-linear.

So the output of the softmax layer is: softmax( weight_matrix * input_activation)

weight_matrix * input_activation is purely linear combination of features.

The question is: if the application of the softmax activation still yields in a linear classifier or is the model then capable of representing non-linear functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A neural network **with no hidden layers** and a softmax output layer is exactly logistic regression (possibly with more than 2 classes), when trained to minimize categorical cross-entropy (equivalently maximize the log-likelihood of a multinomial model).

Your explanation is right on the money: a linear combination of inputs learns linear functions, and the softmax function yields a probability vector over classes.